# Pass title of product into order in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models

I want to be able to view the title of a product that has been ordered rather than having to cross reference order ids from different fields. I have tried using ForeignKey but it doesnt automatically set the product title. I have to manually select from dropdown list.

**PRODUCT/PHOTO**

```
class Photograph(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False,
                              upload_to="photos/", default="default.png")
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    description = models.TextField()
```

**ORDER**

```
*class Order(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_STATUS_PENDING = 'P'
    PAYMENT_STATUS_COMPLETE = 'C'
    PAYMENT_STATUS_FAILED = 'F'

    PAYMENT_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (PAYMENT_STATUS_PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (PAYMENT_STATUS_COMPLETE, 'Complete'),
        (PAYMENT_STATUS_FAILED, 'Failed')
    ]
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    order_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=PAYMENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=PAYMENT_STATUS_PENDING
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)*
```

**OrderItem**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Photograph, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    order_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_id)
    
    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total
```

**This is where I want to see the product title which has been ordered.**

[image: Order]

Comment: Your `Order` does not seem to refer to any `Photograph`/product at all?

Comment: I added a model, sorry I missed it.

Comment: It is still not entirely clear to me what the problem is. You can use `self.product.title` in a method/property of your `OrderItem`. But since an order can have multiple `Photograph`s, it thus can not use the title, since there can be multiple ones.